# How modify sequence numbers based on one changed sequence number in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

How to change the rest sequence numbers when one sequence number changed. Then sort the rows based on sequence number. Here's the example:

```
  seq_nbr
A 1        |   A 1       |  A 1
B 2 -> 5   |   B 5       |  C 2
C 3        |   C 3 -> 2  |  D 3
D 4        |   D 4 -> 3  |  E 4
E 5        |   E 5 -> 4  |  B 5
```

Comment: What do you expect if you change 5 to 1?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov, If that, the result will be A2, B3, C4, D5

Comment: I meant B = 1. What if you change B to 1? How are you going to determine which one has changed?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov, I didn't answer it correctly in your last question. If change B to 1, the answer would be B1, A2, C3, D4, E5. It's based on the sequence number. If changed to a smaller sequence number, an item with a larger sequence number compared to the new one should be changed accordingly. If changed to a larger sequence number, an item with a smaller sequence number should be changed accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the new sequence number assigned to B is greater than the old one, the sequence numbers between the old and the new value are pushed down (subract 1), to keep the consecutive numbering in that column.

Sayan M asked you in a comment what the desired result is if you change the sequence number to a **lower** value rather than higher. Presumably in that case all the sequence numbers between the old and new value must be pushed up (add 1), to keep the consecutive numbering.

The `update` statement below addresses both cases (as well as the trivial case when the sequence number doesn't change - it's updated to itself). It does not require analytic functions and it works as an `update` statement.

I assume the same table and column names as in MT0's answer, and the inputs are a "value" and a "new sequential number" (such as "B" and "5") - given as bind variables.

```
update 
  (
    select value, seq_nbr,
           (select seq_nbr from table_name where value = :i_value) as old_nbr
    from   table_name
  )
  set seq_nbr = 
    case when value = :i_value then :i_nbr
         else seq_nbr + case when :i_nbr > old_nbr then -1 else 1 end
    end
  where :i_nbr != old_nbr 
    and seq_nbr between least(:i_nbr, old_nbr) and greatest(:i_nbr, old_nbr)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `MERGE` statement with the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  WITH new_seq_nbr (value, new_nbr) AS (
    SELECT 'B', 5 FROM DUAL                       -- Your change goes here.
  )
  SELECT t.ROWID AS rid,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           ORDER BY
             CASE t.value
             WHEN n.value
             THEN 2 * new_nbr + 1
             ELSE 2 * seq_nbr
             END
         ) AS new_seq_nbr
  FROM   table_name t
         CROSS JOIN new_seq_nbr n
) src
ON (src.rid = dst.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET dst.seq_nbr = src.new_seq_nbr
  WHERE dst.seq_nbr <> src.new_seq_nbr;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value PRIMARY KEY, seq_nbr UNIQUE) AS
SELECT 'A', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'F', 6 FROM DUAL;
```

After then `MERGE` then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY seq_nbr;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | SEQ_NBR |
> | --- | --- |
> | A | 1 |
> | C | 2 |
> | D | 3 |
> | E | 4 |
> | B | 5 |
> | F | 6 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=38d6b557132c6efb798690bde07aeda7)*